# Inheritance and polymorphic-associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, polymorphic-associations

I have a **User** model, which belongs to **Profile** (belongs_to polymorphic). One model comes in two subclasses, but the *profile_type* in *User* always correspond to the parent model.

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile, :polymorphic => true

SomeProf < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :profile

SomeDeepProf1 < SomeProf

SomeDeepProf2 < SomeProf
```

Then:

```
sdp1 = SomeDeepProf1.new
user = sdp1.create_user
user.profile_type
> 'SomeProf'
```

Even stating the association in subclasses, the **profile_type** remains *SomeProf*.

Why does this happen? Is there any way profile_type match subclass and not the parent class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the `_type` column is supposed to identify the model's table and should not contain data on the model itself - just a reference.

However if you inspect `user.profile.type` it should return `SomeDeepProf1`.

Comment: Yes Marcel, I noticed it. My code is using profile_type to decide the type of User and avoid extra access to the database. Thanks for the explanation!