# Rails Polymorphic Associations without STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252757/inheritance-and-polymorphic-associations-in-rails) describes my problem very well, but the answer to that post assumes that you use Single Table Inheritance (STI) for subclasses. In my case the subclasses of `SomeProf` has their own tables and since the `_type` column is storing the class name of the superclass, this is not working. In my equivalent to `SomeDeepProf1` I have declared that `self.table_name = 'some_other_table'` and I would not like to use STI since the subclasses of my equivalent to `SomeProf` have very different attributes.

Any suggestion of how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Right now I am using the following workaround to solve this in the `SomeDeepProf1` class:

`before_create :set_poly_type_to_class_name
...
def set_poly_type_to_class_name
  self.profile_type = self.profile.class.name
end`

Comment: Unfortunately this is not work all the way... It seems as it's the class `SomeDeepProf1` that think the `profile_type`should be `SomeProf`and not `SomeDeepProf1`. In my model I have a has_many : through relationship from the `SomeProf`class and if I try to go from `SomeDeepProf1` to that has_many :through relationship, the query will be `["profile_type", "SomeProf"]`. How can I change the query to check for `SomeDeepProf1`instead of `SomeProf`?